# Can I use my own UI to authenticate users with Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to use Azure AD B2C to authenticate users of an Angular2 single-page app. I understand I can use the UI (either default or customized) that is associated with each Azure AD B2C policy. For a number of reasons I am not happy with the Azure AD B2C UI (or the effort required to customize it).

Therefore I'd like to use my own UI within my app that would just make calls to Azure AD B2C. Is that possible? If so, how?  I have looked at Azure AD B2C Custom Policies, but I an not sure if those still use the default (or customized) Azure AD B2C UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**At this time, the only way to authenticate Azure AD B2C users is through the Azure AD B2C hosted UIs (either default or customized).**

If you want to completely create your own and "*make an API call*" to B2C to get a token, you'd be using the OAuth Resource Owner Password Grant which Azure AD B2C does not support yet.

You can support this feature ask and get updates on its progress by voting for it in the Azure AD B2C feedback forum: [Add support for Resource Owner Password Credentials flow in Azure AD B2C](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/13817784-add-support-for-resource-owner-password-credential).

Comment: Just voted for it.  Good to see I am not the only one who wants this. "**Private** preview available in a few months" is not the good news I was hoping for though.