# Azure AD B2C: Is it possible to use username and password in custom form for authentication

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have an existing iOS application that uses a custom form with login/password. 
I want to use Azure Active Directory B2C for authentication. It is possible to do this by popping out the browser. But is it possible to save my custom login form?

Comment: there is a similar post in SO @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42943391/authenticate-a-user-on-azure-ad-b2c-using-graph-api

Comment: What do you mean by "is it possible to save my custom login form"? Do you want the login form in AAD B2C to look the same as your custom login form?

Comment: No, I mean to make a request to AD with username/password and do not pop out browser.

Comment: Feature is now available in preview: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51545075/336378

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**At this time, the only way to authenticate Azure AD B2C users is through the Azure AD B2C hosted UIs (either default or customized) that are invoked by popping out a browser window / web view.**

If you want to completely create your own and custom login form, you'd be using the OAuth Resource Owner Password Grant which Azure AD B2C does not support yet.

You can support this feature ask and get updates on its progress by voting for it in the Azure AD B2C feedback forum: [Add support for Resource Owner Password Credentials flow in Azure AD B2C](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/13817784-add-support-for-resource-owner-password-credential).

*Note: same answer as [Can I use my own UI to authenticate users with Azure AD B2C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46493650/can-i-use-my-own-ui-to-authenticate-users-with-azure-ad-b2c/46494792#46494792)*