# Can I use Azure B2C with my own login form?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have an existing login page. Can I integrate Azure B2C into it instead of using the login screens provided by and hosted by Azure AD B2C?

A similar question was asked 4 years ago but the answer is most likely out of date: [Can I use my own UI to authenticate users with Azure AD B2C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46493650/can-i-use-my-own-ui-to-authenticate-users-with-azure-ad-b2c)

Comment: I hate add some links here. But it is possible. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-user-flow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui?pivots=b2c-user-flow https://thecodeblogger.com/2021/03/23/creating-custom-login-page-in-azure-ad-b2c/

Comment: That is not a solution to my question. That says "After content is loaded from your URL, it's merged with an HTML fragment inserted by Azure AD B2C, and then the page is displayed to your customer.".. which to me sounds like the form is controlled by B2C. I want to control the form myself.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at the [embedded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/embedded-login?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) sign up / sign-in option.

"For a simpler sign-up or sign-in experience, you can avoid redirecting users to a separate sign-up or sign-in page, or generating a pop-up window. By using the inline frame  HTML element, you can embed the Azure AD B2C sign-in user interface directly into your web application."

Answer (score 2):

If you are really determined to use the form of your own which has nothing to do with AAD B2C then the only solution you're left with is a Resource Owner Password Credentials grant where you explicitely send username/email and password over to AAD B2C and get a token in return.

Here's docs ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-user-flow

Be aware though that this flow is not suitable for modern applications for security reasons and in principle should rather be used only for legacy solutions.